# How to make dependency project visible for Ios app?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kotlin multiplatform project `MusicFeature` with targets for **ios**, **android**, **common** with the following build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation(project(":ProjectUtils"))
            }
        }
        androidMain {
        }

        iosMain {
            
        }
    }
```

`ProjectUtils` is also a multiplatform project.

There's no troubles in using `ProjectUtils` code from `MusicFeature`. But when I export `MusicFeature` as a **framework** for iOS, I don't have access to *classes* from `ProjectUtils`.

Comment: I guess you are looking for `transitiveExport = true`. You can find out more reference [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-build-native-binaries.html#export-dependencies-to-binaries).

Comment: @shadowsheep Thanks. That what I was looking for. You can make it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `transitiveExport = true` for your framework.

```
binaries {
   framework {
       export project(':dependency')
       // Export transitively.
       transitiveExport = true
   }
}
```

You can find more reference here in [export dependencies to binaries](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-build-native-binaries.html#export-dependencies-to-binaries).